# Using Remark instead of Note

Tags: idioms

I ran across this sentence:

> Remark the small differences between this procedure and the one
>   written by xxx.

Is this valid usage in English? I would typially write "note the small ..." or "notice the small ..."

Answer (score 1):

It's a [hopelessly archaic usage](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=remark%20the%20difference&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)...

[image]

Much the same applies to [**mark** the difference](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mark%20the%20difference&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=). Today we'd normally say [**note** the difference](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=remark%20the%20difference,mark%20the%20difference,note%20the%20difference&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=).